# Erlang ODBC parameter query with null parameters

Tags: erlang, null, odbc, parameters

Is it possible to pass null values to parameter queries?  For example

```
Sql = "insert into TableX values (?,?)".
Params = [{sql_integer, [Val1]}, {sql_float, [Val2]}].

% Val2 may be a float, or it may be the atom, undefined

odbc:param_query(OdbcRef, Sql, Params).
```

Now, of course odbc:param_query/3 is going to complain if Val2 is undefined when trying to match to a sql_float, but my question is...  Is it possible to use a parameterized query, such as:

```
Sql = "insert into TableY values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)".
```

with any null parameters?  I have a use case where I am dumping a large number of real-time data into a database by either inserting or updating.  Some of the tables I am updating have a dozen or so nullable fields, and I do not have a guarantee that all of the data will be there.

Concatenating a SQL together for each query, checking for null values seems complex, and the wrong way to do it.

Having a parameterized query for each permutation is simply not an option.

Any thoughts or ideas would be fantastic!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the atom `null` to denote a null value. For instance:

```
Sql = "insert into TableX values (?,?)".
Params = [{sql_integer, [Val1]}, {sql_float, [null]}].
```

Comment: Hello, it seems that this topic little bit old, but question is still actual. Despite that docs says value could be `value() = null | term()` this little example illustrate a problem: `odbc:param_query(NewRef, "SELECT ? as fff", [{sql_integer, [123]}]).`odbc:param_query(NewRef, "SELECT ? as fff", [{sql_integer, [null]}]).
** exception exit: {badarg,odbc,param_query,'Params'}
     in function  odbc:decode/1`
{selected,["fff"],[{123}]}